# Comodule analogue for statement that a faithful representation of an affine group scheme generates all

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, comodules

If $V$ is a faithful finite dimensional representation of an affine group scheme $G$ over a field $k$, then every finite dimensional representation of $G$ is isomorphic to a subquotient of $\otimes^n (V \oplus V^*)$, where $V^*$ is the dual representation (see for instance [Milne, Basic theory of affine group schemes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf), VIII, Theorem 11.7).

The question is whether there is an analogue of this statement for possibly non-commutative Hopf algebras instead of affine group schemes and comodules instead of representations. The first question is what a is a good analogue of the property of a representation to be faithful. In the case of commutative Hopf algebras a condition is given in VIII, Lemma 11.6 Milnes notes. I am not sure if this is suitable in general. Please excuse this question being rather vague.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at this paper of Rieffel http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186936790018X

It has the analogue for Hopf algebras.

Comment: Thank you for this reference! I guess you refer to Corollary 1 in this paper. It is restricted to Hopf algebras of finite dimension. Given a (f.d.) Hopf algebra $H$, it deals with "representations of $H$", i.e. algebra homomorphisms from $H$ into the algebra of endomorphisms of a vector space $V$. I was however rather thinking about $H$-comodules. In the finite-dimensional case one can pass to the dual of a Hopf algebra and I guess the results of this paper will provide an analogue in the spirit I was thinking of. But is there anything known about $H$-comodules for $H$ not of finite dimension?

Comment: My point is that the analogue of faithful is not factoring through a quotient Hopf algebra and Corollary 1 implies any finite dimensional irreducible rep is a constituent in a tensor power.  For an infinite dimensional irrep it will be a subquotient of the sum of all tensor powers.

Comment: You might look at http://www.math.wisc.edu/~passman/burnside.pdf too.